# How to re-organize and not duplicate a MongoDB document based on user input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with Node.js, Mongoose and MongoDB. Testing in Postman.

2 users can answer questions. I want to organize, and later display these questions and the 2 user's answers too. I could achieve that the 2 user's answers are separated into two different arrays. But what I want is: the questions shouldn't duplicate, answers should be attached to the questions that are answered by both users.

With this code, I almost achieved the desired result but it's not perfect. Please see below my expected outcome.

```
        let user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        let user2 = await User.find({ matched: user.email });

        let answer = await Answer.find({
            by: user.email,
        });
        let answer2 = await Answer.find({
            by: user2[0].email,
        });

        var array = [];
        var allAnswers = {};
        allAnswers["1"] = answer;
        allAnswers["2"] = answer2;
        array.push(allAnswers);

        res.json(allAnswers);
```

Not-so-good outcome:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "question": "Question1",
            "answer": "some answer",
            "by": "user2"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "question": "Question1",
            "answer": "some answer",
            "by": "user1"
        },
        {
            "question": "Question2",
            "answer": "some answer",
            "by": "user1"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected and desired outcome:**

```
{
        "Question1": [
            {
                "answer": "some answer",
                "by": "user2"
            },
            {
                "answer": "some answer",
                "by": "user1"
            }
        ],
        "Question2": [
            {
                "answer": "some answer",
                "by": "user1"
            }
        ]
}
```

Since user2 did not answer Question2, I do not want to display that:

```
{
            "Question1": [
                {
                    "answer": "some answer",
                    "by": "user2"
                },
                {
                    "answer": "some answer",
                    "by": "user1"
                }
            ],
 }
```

**And there could be hundreds of related questions of course but only two user answers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xinNqgjGK0U)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$question",
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data._id": 0,
      "data.question": 0
    }
  }
])
```

It groups by question and projects only what is needed.

Comment: This is nice. Thank you. Do I need to add a timestamp to sort them descending? Right now every time I send the get request, it sorts them randomly.

Comment: You can do it using $sort.